# How to replace text in gtext ( R / gWidgets )?

Tags: r, gwidgets

Suppose (using R/gWidgets) we have a simple text window like this:

```
require(gWidgets)
textwin <- gtext("The camel grazes in the desert.", container=gwindow())
```

When selecting text with the mouse we can retrieve the selected text.

```
svalue(textwin, drop=T) # returns text
## [1] "grazes"
```

Now my question is: **Is there a way of replacing the selected text in a gtext?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the whole string and the selected string.

```
all_text <- svalue(textwin, index=0)
selected_text <- svalue(textwin, index=0, drop = TRUE)
```

Then find the index of the selected substring using `regexpr`.

```
rx_match <- regexpr(selected_text, all_text, fixed = TRUE)
```

Replace that substring with something else.

```
substring(
  all_text, 
  rx_match, 
  rx_match + attr(rx_match, "match.length") - 1
) <- "monkey"
```

Update the textbox.

```
svalue(textwin) <- all_text
```

---

Plan B: manipulate the return value from `svalue` with `index = 1`.  This is nearly right, but I think that there's a bug in `gWidgets` that stop it from working generally.

```
# Get the index of the lines/character positions to start and finish
i <- format(svalue(textwin, index = 1, drop = TRUE), digits = 3)
i <- sapply(strsplit(i, "\\."), as.numeric)

# Get all the text as a character vector
all_text <- svalue(textwin, index=0)
all_text <- strsplit(all_text, "\n")[[1]]

# Replace the selected portion
replacement <- "monkey"

if(i[1, 1] == i[1, 2])
{
  svalue(textwin) <- substring(all_text[i[1, 1]], i[2, 1], i[2, 2])
} else
{
    all_text[i[1, 1]] <- paste0(
      substring(all_text[i[1, 1]], 1, i[2, 1]),  
      replacement,
      substring(all_text[i[1, 2]], 1, i[2, 2])
    )
    svalue(textwin) <- all_text[-((i[1, 1] + 1):(i[1, 2]))]
}
```

The big problem is with the call to `format` that turns the index numbers into strings.  It doesn't play well with positions in single digit versus double digit positions.  I'm fairly certain that this is a bug in `getMethod(.svalue, signature("gTexttcltk", "guiWidgetsToolkittcltk"))`  (though there might be problems in other toolkits too).

Comment: But RegExp does not know the position of the cursor, this only works if the extracted pattern is unique or the first occurrence; else (with repeating pattern) we cannot decide which pattern match to choose. To put it different, this will not work if I marked the last "grazes" in this sentence: ``The camel grazes in the desert and grazes and grazes.`` I would get: ``The camel monkey in the desert and grazes and grazes.`` instead of ``The camel grazes in the desert and grazes and monkey.``

Comment: Hah, that's good -- it only works for me with tcltk and not with GTK, but I do not mind -- but this *** *** *!?")§* reformatting of ``1.1`` and ``1.10`` into ``1.1`` (first line first character) makes it all useless at the moment, right?. -- thanks for the effort

Comment: @marvin_dpr Yeah, it's broken.  Send a bug report to John Verzani.  He's good about fixing things.  You can get his contact details from `packageDescription("gWidgets", fields = "Maintainer")`.

Answer (score 1):

Since Richie says I'm good about fixing things, here you go:

In `gWidgets2` this feature has been added to the development versions on github. Use devtools to install.

I'm trying to only fix bugs in gWidgets and this is a new feature, so I'm not going to add it there. However, here is some code you can easily use within your project:

```
library(RGtk2)    
replace_selected <- function(gtext_widget, value) {

  view <- gtext_widget@widget@widget

  buffer <- view$getBuffer()

  bnds <- buffer$getSelectionBounds()

  if(bnds$retval) {

    buffer$insert(bnds$start, as.character(value), -1)

    new_bnds <- buffer$getSelectionBounds()

    buffer$delete(new_bnds$start, new_bnds$end)

  }
}

## replace_selected in gWidgetstcltk

replace_selected <- function(gtext_widget, value) {

  widget <- gtext_widget@widget@widget

  range <- as.numeric(tktag.ranges(widget, "sel"))

  if (length(range) > 0)

     tcl(widget,"replace", "sel.first", "sel.last", value)

}
```

Comment: The use if the list was messing with the code block.  I don't know why exactly but removing the bullets fixed that.